# Visual Studio 2017 not updating references

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a VS solution with three projects. When I make changes to the class library the references doesn't update and it keeps expecting the old namespaces and classes and results in error when building since it can't find the old namespace.

It also results in build errors if I try "using LC.Tools.API.Models" since it can't find the namespace and intellisense shows the old namespaces (LC.Tools.API.Model) with the old classes.

The solution contains two ASP.NET Core web projects and one ASP.NET Core Class Library. The class library is referenced as a project reference in the other two projects.

I've tried deleting the bin and obj folder on all projects, re added the references, rebuild, build, clean solution.. Is there a way I can fix this without having to recreate the projects?

Comment: try to restart VS

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes had similar issue in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Solved it by right clicking on project in Solution Explorer and then choose the "**Unload the project**" option and after that right click on unloaded project again and choose "**Reload the project**".